# Linker dropping characters on object files passed into it?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, arm, cross-compiling

I seem to have run into a strange anomaly with ARM-Linux cross compilation on a Windows machine. I am using the Sourcery CodeBench Lite Edition (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc) obtained from Mentor Graphic's website.

http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/editions/lite-edition/

Previously, I have built my code on a Ubuntu machine using an arm-linux compiler (sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabi -y || gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi). The tools work fine here, I can build object files and link them together no problem.

The problem is when I do the ARM-Linux cross compilation in Windows.. more specifically, the linking phase. Here is the linker command in my make file

```
  %.elf: $(OBJ_C_OMAP)
       @echo "linking to make ELF"
       @echo $(OBJ_C_OMAP)
       @echo "-------------------------------"
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_C_OMAP) --output $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

OBJ_C_OMAP contains a list of all the object files and their full paths, CFLAGS is a bunch of compiler flags and LDFLAGS is one linker flag. When it gets to this point the Linker churns through and it eventually throws out an error:

```
<full_path_to_an_object_file>: No such file or directory
```

When examining the `<full_path_to_an_object_file>` it seems there is a character missing. If i compare this string to what @echo $(OBJ_C_OMAP) gives us, there is a mis-match, the  $(OBJ_C_OMAP) variable contains the correct path, but for whatever reason, the linker is mis-interperting it. As an example of what happens:

/ad2_ra/ap/modules/gps/gps_ubx_ucenter.o: No such file or directory

When the directory specified in $(OBJ_C_OMAP) shows

/ad2_raw/ap/modules/gps/gps_ubx_ucenter.o

In this example, the 'w' character is missing.

In addition to this strange behavior, if I remove this object file from the list, the problem persists on another .o file (another char removed from the path). It's as if there is some limitation on how many obj files I can pass in, once it reaches a certain # of obj files to pass in it starts removing characters from path and errors out.

This could be a bug or maybe some limitation in the Lite version of this compiler (which i'm using). Also note that I am linking quite a "few" objects (around ~66 files), I'm not sure if there are special considerations to be made when linking this many for this compiler.

Assistance appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I searched around and found an incredibly similar problem reported to Atmel with avr-gcc:

http://asf.atmel.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1965

The issues seems to be that Windows is only capable of accepting 8191 characters per command line.  Is your link step command line call over that limit? (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473)

Answer (score 1):

Incredible. As you say, Windows, did you try running some kind of anti-virus software then?

"Linker dropping characters on object files passed into it?" that's how you called the post. But, reading it, that's altogether clear the linker is the last thing to blame as you're passing wrong arguments to it. That could rather be the gnu MAKE, I'd check that first.

Be *absolutely* sure you have the latest MAKE. And it *did* save me a lot of time on many UNIX systems (never Windows, sorry). I was nagging the gnu people those days. They were quite normal, and they'd make a patch if you happen to really convince them. And you *should* file a bug any time you find such one, the programmers' society would just be thankful for that.

Another thing, is the environment where you're building. This might be a culprit as well, Cygwin or whatever. That said, either upgrade or, again, file them a bug. Because the things you exoerience, should never happen.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed looks like a bug dependent on the command line length. As a workaround, you could use gcc's option [`@file`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) to read command-line options from *file*, thereby shortening the command line, e. g.

```
       @echo $(OBJ_C_OMAP) >obj.txt
       @echo "-------------------------------"
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) @obj.txt --output $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: On windows this will still not work because you get the same 8191 line length limit. The only difference is that you get it in the @echo command in stead of in the compiler.
Maybe have a look [here](https://mcuoneclipse.com/2015/03/29/solving-the-8192-character-command-line-limit-on-windows/) for inspiration how to work around the problem

Comment: Whether this will work depends on the resulting length of the @echo command, which likely is shorter than the original $(CC) command. Also there may be other ways to put the list of all the object files into a file.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, GNU Make can write arbitrary text into files without invoking an external command. This is done using the [file function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html#File-Function), which has specific example code for cases like this.